# How does I/O-methods like read() put a Thread in blocked state in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, blocked-threads

So, if i have understood this correctly, a thread goes into waiting state when we call wait on an object and it goes into blocked state when it is waiting for a lock on an object(like when trying to get into a synchronized block or method).

How does I/O-methods like read() put a Thread in a blocked state though? I understand WHY it has to be in a blocked state, waiting for data that it can read but i'm also interested in HOW. How does the JVM notify the thread that it can continue when data in the resource its trying to read, is available again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't change the state of the thread to BLOCKED

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Thread main = Thread.currentThread();
    new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(main + " is in "+main.getState()+" state");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }
        }
    }).start();
    System.in.read();
}
```

prints

```
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
Thread[main,5,main] is in RUNNABLE state
```

instead the OS doesn't return from the `read` until there is some data  and the OS decides whether and when to context switch the thread/process.

> How does the JVM notify the thread that it can continue when data in the resource its trying to read, is available again?

The OS wakes the thread when there is more data or the stream has been closed. The JVM doesn't get involved.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the native platform.

In POSIX, a call to [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) usually blocks until data is available, but there are many other reasons to return, such as an end-of-file was reached, the file descriptor was closed, the operation timed out or a signal interrupted the operation.

In Windows, the most closely related function is [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

The gory details, refering to Java 8 update 112 b15:

[`FileInputStream.read`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/60767ec3909b/src/share/classes/java/io/FileInputStream.java#l206) calls the native [`FileInputStream.read0`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/60767ec3909b/src/share/classes/java/io/FileInputStream.java#l210), implemented natively through JNI in [Java_java_io_FileInputStream_read0](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/60767ec3909b/src/share/native/java/io/FileInputStream.c#l65), which calls [`readSingle`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/60767ec3909b/src/share/native/java/io/io_util.c#l39), which calls `IO_Read`.

In POSIX, [`IO_Read`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/60767ec3909b/src/solaris/native/java/io/io_util_md.h#l70) is defined as [`handleRead`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/60767ec3909b/src/solaris/native/java/io/io_util_md.c#l153), which calls `read`.  The [`RESTARTABLE`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/60767ec3909b/src/solaris/native/java/io/io_util_md.h#l95) macro loops while there's an error and the `errno` is `EINTR`.

In Windows, [`IO_Read`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/60767ec3909b/src/windows/native/java/io/io_util_md.h#l82) is defined as [`handleRead`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/60767ec3909b/src/windows/native/java/io/io_util_md.c#l481), which calls `ReadFile`.